# How can I switch from auto-incremented primary keys to uuids preserving foreign key relationships

Tags: mysql, migration, primary-key, uuid

I have a MySQL database with about 40 or so tables in it. I've realized that in order to scale, I'm going to need to switch from using MySQL Auto-incremented IDs to uuids instead.

How can I migrate from Auto-Incremented integer primary keys to using uuids for my primary keys?

I also need to preserve the foreign key relationships.

I'm considering options here on what's the best way to accomplish this but it doesn't seem like there's a non-trivial way to do it.

Does anyone know if there's a way to map a database to a new schema with MySQL workbench or script it nicely?

What's the least painful way to accomplish this?

Comment: What rate of inserts per second are you having that you want to switch to UUIDs?

Comment: @TheImpaler The reason I want to switch to UUIDs is because I'm implementing Domain-Driven Design and would like to be able to create Domain objects without having to make a round-trip to the database first.